# Zend PDF trying to print Russian language

Tags: php, pdf, ibm-midrange, zend-pdf

I am using Zend PDF, trying to print Russian words.  My code is

```
$unicodeString = "это фигня";

$page->drawText($unicodeString, 72, 720, 'UTF-8');
```

but the result is `Ñ•Ñ‚Ð¾ Ñ„Ð¸Ð³Ð½Ñ•`

So, it is printing something weird. I read that the issue might have to do with fonts and Unicode, so I am planning to fix it by doing this:

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('/Library/Fonts/Times New Roman Bold.ttf');
```

How can i find the path to this font in on an IBM i / AS/400 machine?

One more very basic question. The font will be coming from the server. What I understand is that the fonts should be on the server, Zend PDF is just finding the font by name. The font is not part of the Zend framework . Is my understanding correct?

I am just curious how a Chinese or in general a non-English language speaker will access a website like Google, Yahoo, or StackOverflow.  What i am trying to ask is, if the person doesn't know English  and the keyboard  is not in English how they will type the url?  Or am I completely wrong?

Is the url in English only?

```
google.com      谷歌随着
```

Is the above is possible or not?

Comment: Zod, the first part of your question is about rendering Russian text.  The second part of the question is about the internationalized domain name system - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name.  Are these two parts related?  If not, may I suggest removing the second part and placing it in a separate question?

Answer (score 1):

True Type fonts are optional on the IBM i.  Have your IBM admin look at this web page: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzalu/rzalucontruetype.htm  If this doesn't fit your needs, have the admin create a directory for you and copy the fonts you need into that.

Comment: Thanks for resposnse. i look into the font folder. its empty!. you know where we can download TNR.PFB font files. Is it possible

Comment: That is a PostScript font, not True Type.  You should be able to find it in /QIBM/ProdData/OS400/Fonts/PSFonts/Latin

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the intricacies of Unicode and PHP on the [IBM i](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/) but the Microsoft TrueType Core Fonts can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/corefonts/files/the%20fonts/final/.

You may want to review the [licensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web#Program_termination_and_software_licence_agreement_issues) and how it relates to your application.