# Zend PDF printing Russian and Chinese

Tags: php, zend-framework, ibm-midrange, zend-pdf

I am using Zend Framework on Zend Server for IBM i

I am trying to generate a pdf in chinese snd russian . I am getting different errors

I read that that there are some limittations in i5 OS . If any body have succesfully generated the zend pdf in russian or chinese please let me know.

If you can please post russian hellow world code :-)

I TRY THIS , BUT NOT WORKING

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('/qibm/ProdData/OS400/Fonts/PSFonts/Latin/TNR.PFB');
//$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('CYRIL1.TTF');

$page->setFont($font, 24)
->drawText('Российская Федерация,', 60, 300, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: "I am getting different errors" - WHAT errors?

Comment: if you have printed the  zend pdf in hungarian language , just tell me how you did that . Ok no need to post the regual SO comments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend PDF trying to print Russian language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434816/zend-pdf-trying-to-print-russian-language)

Comment: what possible duplicate man i dont get answer